# differential equation with separable with Separable Variables

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Hi I've solved the Differential equation:

$$ x ln(x) dy + \sqrt{ 1+y^{2}}dx =0 $$

Domain of the equations in my opinion should be $ x >0 $(becuase of logarithm right?)

I'm dividing equation by $\sqrt{1+y^{2}} \cdot x ln(x)$ and I'm obtaining equation:

$$ \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^{2}}} + \frac{dx}{x ln(x)} $$

Next, because:
$$ \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^{2}}} = ln\left\lvert \sqrt{1+y^{2}} + y \right\rvert  + C $$ 
And:
$$ \int \frac{dx}{x ln(x)} = ln \left\lvert ln(x)  \right\rvert + C   $$

So the answer in my opinion should be:

$$\left\lvert (\sqrt{1+y^{2}} +y) + ln(x)  \right\rvert = C $$

where of course  $ x > 0 $

I Don't know why in book from equations come from the answer is:

$$ ln \left\lvert x \right\rvert (y+ \sqrt{1+y^{2}}) = C $$, $ x \neq 0, x \neq  1$
Is that correct answer really?

Answer (score 1):

Error FOUND: $\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}=\ln |\sqrt{1+y^2} +y|$ as you said..   but in the next step, you your self wrote it wrong.
It comes out to be $$\\ln |\sqrt{1+y^2} +y|+\ln|\ln(x)|=ln(C)$$Please note that we can write $C$ as $\ln C$ as both are constants.
Thus this now simply gives you:
$$\ln|{x}|(\sqrt{1+y^2}+y)=C$$

Cheers.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer. But I still don't know from here is : $ ln | x | $ ? Instead should not be : $| ln(x) |$ ?

Comment: To maintain logarithmic domain, it is important that $x>0$ thus i think $\ln  |x|$ is justified.